Google provider not showing up in Django admin and getting ImproperlyConfigured error after setting up django-allauth
I'm encountering two issues after setting up Django Allauth for authentication in my Django project:

The Google provider option is not showing up in the dropdown list
when navigating to the "Add social application" section of the
Django admin panel.
When attempting to access the sign-in page (/enrolled/sign-in/), I'm
getting an "ImproperlyConfigured" error with the message "unknown
provider: google".

I followed the setup instructions provided in the Django Allauth documentation and added the necessary configuration for the Google provider in my settings file. Despite this, I'm facing these issues.
Here is my settings.py file:
"""
Django settings for temp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.11.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-x5242^+u0mit3om8z)e=8i$(vi!o@7$ks1om9*@7r(lo(=!3y!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'temp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        # For each OAuth based provider, either add a ``SocialApp``
        # (``socialaccount`` app) containing the required client
        # credentials, or list them here:
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '123',
            'secret': '456',
            'key': ''
        }
    }
}

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'temp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

In the Django admin, I'm unable to see Google in the dropdown option of providers. In many YouTube videos, it's shown that the provider name appears as you selected it in your INSTALLED_APPS.
Django Admin
Now, this is my django template:
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load socialaccount %}
    
    {% block extra_head %}
        <link rel="preload" href="{% static 'order/css/sign-in-form.css' %}" as="style">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'order/css/sign-in-form.css' %}">
    {% endblock %}
    
    {% block dynamic_content %}
        <div class="button-container">
            <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}" class="login-button">
                <i class="fa-google fa-brands fa-xl"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}

I'm getting this error:unknown provider: google
Unknown Provider error
And this error is pointing out to this line:
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}" class="login-button">

Your assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

I also struggled with this problem very seriously and finally found a solution.
pip install django-allauth[socialaccount]
Since my legacy is using pipenv, the following worked:
pipenv install "django-allauth[socialaccount]"

for zsh, add a double-quotes: pip install "django-allauth[socialaccount]"
